# How does Slack create a phone ringing from a push notification? (iOS,Android)

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, telephony

I am familiar with sending push notification payloads to mobile apps where the user can open the notification, passing the payload to the app.

I am somewhat familiar with Android's ability to receive data only push notifications that do not show up on the OS menu.

What I do not understand is how call applications like Slack receive pushes and create a ringing screen and continuously call the user like a phone call.

Is this just a long sound file, or are they integrating with the iOS/Android OS telephony?

Comment: On Android it could be https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip, On iOS: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit VoIP support on both platforms has existed for sometime.

Comment: Hm, thanks! So this must be triggered from a push